# Rails collection to nested json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, collections, nested

I need to convert rails collection to nested json.

**Collection:**

```
    [
       id: 2, name: "Dir 1", parent_id: nil, lft: 1, rgt: 6, depth: 0, 
       id: 3, name: "Dir 2", parent_id: nil, lft: 7, rgt: 8, depth: 0, 
       id: 9, name: "Dir 2.1", parent_id: 2, lft: 2, rgt: 3, depth: 1,  
       id: 10, name: "Dir 2.2", parent_id: 2, lft: 4, rgt: 5, depth: 1 
       ...
    ]
```

**output json**

```
    [
        { label: "Dir 1", children:[] },
        { label: "Dir 2", children: [
            label: "Dir 2.1", children: [],
            label: "Dir 2.2", children: []
        ]}
        ...
    ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is assuming your collection is tied to a model and you're using [awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set).

```
class Model

  def self.collection_to_json(collection = roots)
    collection.inject([]) do |arr, model|
      arr << { label: model.name, children: collection_to_json(model.children) }
    end
  end

end

# usage: Model.collection_to_json
```

See [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set/wiki/Awesome-nested-set-cheat-sheet) for `roots`.

An alternative to the above, because `awesome_nested_set` appears to produce queries on `model.children` is:

```
class Model

  def self.parents_from_collection
    all.select { |k,v| k[:depth] == 0 }
  end

  def self.children_from_collection(parent)
    all.select { |k,v| k[:parent_id] == parent[:id] }
  end

  def self.collection_to_json(collection = false)
    collection ||= parents_from_collection

    collection.inject([]) do |arr, row|
      children = children_from_collection(row)

      arr << { label: row[:name], children: collection_to_json(children) }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I use gem awesome_nested_set. This method generates a large number of requests? I have a big tree, I can not overload the database

Comment: I did have a functional alternative. I figured awesome_nested_set would have eager loaded to a degree. Unfortunately not. I'll update with the alternative.

Comment: Updated. Be sure to update `self.collection` to fetch all of your model rows. Course, modify as you see fit. The important methods are `children_to_json` and `to_json`.

Comment: To be fair, could probably improve that! ;) and merge those two methods as in first example...

Comment: Updated again. Take note of the `all.select`. This should return `Model.all` (and cache). If you have trouble with that, just replace with a custom method `all_items` and memoize. This will only require a single query.

Comment: Your code works, thank you! I'm sorry, but I don't understand about `all_items` ;) Could you explain about it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38642/discussion-between-vmamaev-and-damien-roche)

Comment: Great! My thinking is `Model.all` might not be cached, and so it might be performing multiple queries at `all.select`. I've updated with `all_items` example.

Comment: I understand, thank you for your explanation and example! The second method generated only one query. it's cool!

Comment: I like the first example, although... it returns a Ruby hash, not JSON. Easily fixed by appending #to_json to the result. I'm not sure what the routine should be called though. collection_to_json.to_json looks a bit weird!

Answer (score 0):

try the to_json method

```
collection.to_json
```

Comment: He wants to convert to a different structure (notice `label`, `children` in his output).